# Error when calculating mean with mutate() dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a new variable as the mean of several other variables in my df with mutate().

I tried the following approaches

```
 df <- df %>%    
       na.omit() %>%     
       mutate(mot_avg = rowMeans(cbind(mot1:mot13)))
```

and

```
df <- df %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(mot_avg = mean(c(mot1:mot13)))
```

and

```
df <- df %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(mot_avg = mean(c(mot1:mot13),na.rm=T))
```

All lead to the following error:

```
 Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.
```

I don't get it; how can there be any missing values, if na.omit() or na.rm=T is used. If I try the code on a smaller sample df it works fine. This is also why I can not give a reproducible example here.

Only if I use baseR code on my df I get what I want with my df.

```
df$mot_avg <- rowMeans(df[,1:14],na.rm=T)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: could you provide sample of your data?

Answer (score 3):

Why not combine the two approaches?

```
library(tidyverse)

#Fake Data
set.seed(3)
x <- bind_cols(lapply(1:10, function(i)rnorm(n = 100, mean = 20)))


##For all variables
first_solution <- x %>% mutate(x = rowMeans(x))

##For a subset of variables
solution_subset <- x %>% mutate(x = rowMeans(x %>% select(V9,V10)))
```